# How to convert PHP cURLcode to C#

Tags: c#

I have no experience in php whatsoever, but I need to create the C# equivalent of this code:

> ```
> <?php
>
> $config['Api-key'] = 'UQ042222gh3TZJ6AWrLB';
>
> $config['Api-secret'] ='UQ042222-RTSmc8ROnCMyNVXnYn9eXAVGi7JhOoug0RTL';
>
> $config['Api-url']  =   'https://uquid.com/api/';
>
> function connectToApi( $endpoint='', $fields = array() )
> {   
> global $config;  
> $ch = curl_init();     
> $url =$config['Api-url'].$endpoint; 
> $fields_string =  http_build_query($fields);  
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-method-override:UQUID', 
> 'Api-key:'.$config['Api-key'], 'Api-secret:'.$config['Api-secret']) );
>
>  $server_output = curl_exec ($ch); 
>  curl_close ($ch);   
>  return $server_output;
> }
>
> function prettyPrint($json){   
> $json = json_decode($json);    
> echo '<pre>'.json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'</pre>'; }
> ```

Please help me.Please Advice me.

Comment: I'm going to assume you haven't just posted your actual secret api key...

Answer (score 1):

I see you are consuming REST service, so try to look at article [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).

Don't forget to add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client reference to your project.

To send post request do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace Api
{
    public class ApiCaller
    {
        public async Task<SomeReceivedEntity> CallApiAsync()
        {
            // prepare client
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://uquid.com/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Api-key", "YourApiKeyString");
                // your other headers ...

                // send request
                var data = new SomeSendedEntity() { ID = 10, Name = "Test" };
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api", data);

                // verify results (throws exception on error response status code)
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                // read, parse and return response
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeReceivedEntity>();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeSendedEntity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeReceivedEntity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Place { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Not tested, but you can find all you need in the article.

Comment: Dear @Fanda, Thanks for your answer. But It have an error.I edited the code like `var data = new SomeSendedEntity() { Api_key = apiKey, Api_secret = apiSecret };
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/account_balance", data);`                          It generated an error when callling client.PostAsJsonAsync.Error is "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"

Comment: This is just-concept code. Watch the stack trace for error details. Api-key etc are used as headers in php code, so set it as headers. I hope these are not real keys. ;-)